# msxml3.dll error in sql

Tags: web-services, sql-server-2008-r2, msxml

Thanks in Advance... when i execute below mentioned part in sql for sending sms using web service, getting error as The operation timed out. Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
            -- Call service to send sms 
            EXEC spHTTPRequest @URI = @ServiceFinalUrl
                ,@methodName = 'POST'
                ,@requestBody = @RequestText
                ,@SoapAction = 'http://tempuri.org/CreateOrderForMe'
                ,@UserName = ''
                ,@Password = ''
                ,@responseText = @xmlOut OUT
```

[image]

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Iam using sql server 2008 R2